# Integral One-to-one functions in 3 dimensions

Tags: functions

I am looking for a integer-valued one-to-one function that maps coordinates $(x,y,z)$ in space $\mathbb{Z^+}$ to intergers in $\mathbb{Z^+}$?

Comment: The set of positive integers . Changed it to Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x_i\}_0^\infty$ the decimal representation of $x$, that is
$$
x = \sum_0^\infty x_i\cdot 10^i
$$
Now to obtain an injective function $f$, you can take as image of $(x, y, z)$ the number whose decimal representation is
$$
(x_0, y_0, z_0, x_1, y_1, z_1,x_2, y_2, z_2,\dots)
$$
Finally, if you want a function which is also onto, you can use the following one
$$
(x, y, z) \to f(x - 1, y - 1, z - 1) + 1
$$

Comment: I was also wondering , if I have $n$ such tuples ${(x,y,z)}$ , is it possible to come up with a mapping that maps these to ${1..n}$ ?

Comment: Of course. You can arbitrarily link each one of those $n$ tuples, $(x, y, z)$, to one number in $\{1,\dots, n\}$, so there are $n!$ different such maps.

Comment: Note however, AlbertH's solution provides a unique integer for every unique tuple. To ensure the same for a function mapping to integers in the range of one to n requires knowledge of all tuples that are yet to be mapped.